# RandomForest classification model with 100% accuracy is it real or something wrong?

Tags: classification, random-forest, spark-mllib

Hi I am new to machine learning. I just created my first working RandomForest classification ml model. It works amazingly well no error and accuracy is 100%. I have used Apache Spark MLlib to implement this algorithm. Other machine learning experts around say 100% accuracy is like dream we never get 100% accuracy is it true? I have trained randomforest classification algo with 95 decision trees and 15 depth of tree. I am using gini impurity and feature strategy as sqrt. I have cross validated my model with test data response values it matches 100%. I have two response values Actionalble/NonActionable. I told my senior I will test model with more data set of real time to see its truthfulness. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you train the model with *nested* cross validation? Selecting hyperparameters at the inner CV and then evaluating out-of-sample performance at the outer CV step?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response how do we do nested cross validation I have 80 % training data and 20% test data I did testing and error calculation on 20% data using model I created. Sorry I am very new to machine learning so please bear with my basic questions.

Comment: It's just like regular CV, except it has 2 steps. CV the whole data set. Take all but 1 fold, and CV partition that data. Then use the inner data to CV select hyperparameters. Then train a model on *all* the inner data, and test the selected model on the holdout set. Repeat for all outer holdout sets.

Comment: Any pointers/links please with R code sample etc to do what you just explained. Though I am using Spark MLlib Java but I will understand R code.

Comment: Just write your own function.

Comment: I am not sure the above comment is very relevant. How big is your data set?

Comment: Hi I have quality data sets of 10 thousands rows out of which I am using 8000 for training and 2000 for testing model

Comment: It's perfectly relevant. Otherwise you're testing on training data, which will bias performance estimates upwards.

Comment: Hi @user777 I am already using random split to split training data and test data and I have ran model multiple times with 100% accuracy. Random split makes sure no bias of training data set no? so don't you think I tried the approach you mentioned in different way

Comment: No, you haven't. You only "get" one out of sample estimate per CV layer. You've used that OOS estimate to select the model hyperparameters. You'll need another batch of out-of-sample data to estimate performance for the selected hyperparameters in any reasonable fashion.

Comment: @user777 is right. For an example of nested cross-validation, please refer to http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/basic-nested-cv.html.

Answer (score 4):

Highly probable you have a "label leakage" in some of the features (feature has 100% correlation with label). E.g. if you have a data like this:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
Feature & Label \\
\hline
1.0 & Actionalble \\
0.0 & NonActionable \\
\hline
\end{array}

Then model can always predict correct label by checking the value of the feature.